# How to config Codeigniter shopping cart to work on subdomains

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, shopping-cart

I'm working on a Multi Site installation of PyroCMS 1.3.2. I have create 3 sites:

The Default site is on my primary domain for the Spanish version, and I have 2 other sites for Italian and English versions of the site on a corresponding subdomain for each one like this:

http://arbioperu.org (spanish)

http://english.arbioperu.org

I have create a PyroCMS Module with Codeigniter Shopping Cart Class wich works fine on my primary domain but dosent work on the subdomain sites. nothing is added to the cart.

I think it my be a problem with the cookies setup:

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) AND $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') ? '' : preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

Thanks for your advice

Comment: Are you sure that $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] contains the domain name that you expect? And not some server name specific for your host?

Answer (score 0):

To allow your cookie to be used on subdomains of `domain.com`, you need to prefix the cookie domain with a period so it looks like `.domain.com`.

Similarly, setting the cookie domain to an empty string as you have will force the cookie to be restricted to use on a single domain.

Using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` will change the cookie domain depending on which site you visit- for example, visiting `a.domain.com` will set the cookie domain as such and therefore visiting `b.domain.com` will act in the same fashion meaning that the cookie domains don't match.